# How do I subtract an input from jtextfield to mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql

How do i subract an input from mysql database?
Let's say I'm doing a bill and inventory system. So when the user input a quantity on a jtextfield, it'd minus off from the table.
will attach the GUI.

right now, i have written this method

```
    public boolean updateBill(Bill bi) {
    boolean success = false;
    dbController db = new dbController();
    PreparedStatement ps;

    try {

        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ooadp?useSSL=false", "root", "pass"); 

        Statement myStatement = myConn.createStatement();

        String sql = "UPDATE medicalproduct SET  quantity =  quantity - ? WHERE productID = ?, productName = ?, dosage = ?, price = ?, status = ?" ;

        myStatement.executeUpdate(sql);



        myConn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return success;

}
```

but then I do not know what to write on my actionPerform and how to link my jtextfield to the sql query.

[This is how my gui looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbXeh.png)

Comment: This is not a valid SQL `WHERE productID = ?, productName = ?, dosage = ?, price = ?, status = ?`

Comment: Between two conditions in `WHERE` clause, you should use `AND`.

Comment: A few things don't seem clear to me looking at your GUI. You called your method `updateBill` but why would that update the medical products? Surely you would be updating that patient's bill rather than the medication itself because that would affect all patients prescribed that drug then. I'd recommend changing to a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to supply parameters to your SQL query which I will show you an example of once questions are answered. Can I suggest you include the `Bill` class definition and if there's a `bill` table

Comment: To answer your question, you DON'T link your JTextfield and the query, you need to pass the value in parameter, value that you need to recover in the view, don't pass the textfield in paramter, this is bad dev ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql statement is invalid anyway... But if am right, all you want to do is subtract from a field in the database by the value specified in a jTextField

```
//For example quantity -= txtfieldValue;
```

If does what you want. You can query for the value of the field, do the subtraction and then finally update the field. Here is an example for updating only the quantity:

```
public void updateQuantity(String txtFieldValue,String id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!!!");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ooadp?useSSL=false", "root", "pass");
        System.out.println("Connection  created!!!");

        PreparedStatement pState;

        String sqlRawP1 ="select quantity from medicalproduct  where productID=?";//I guess medicalproduct is your table name
        pState = conn.prepareStatement(sqlRawP1);
        pState.setString(1, id);
        ResultSet rSetQuantity = pState.executeQuery();

        int countQuantity = 0;
        while(rSetQuantity.next()){
            countQuantity = rSetQuantity.getInt(1);//Am assumming that quantity is an integer
        }

        int value = Interger.parseInt(txtFieldValue);

        countQuantity-= value;

        String sqlRawP2 = "update medicalproduct set quantity=? where productID=?";
        pState = conn.prepareStatement(sqlRawP2);
        pState.setInt(1,countQuantity);
        pState.setString(2, id);

        pState.executeUpdate();

}
```

Hope it will work well..Forgive me if there are minor errors because I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help, but may I ask what should i add onto the action performed for it to call the method?

Comment: Please, I don't really understand what you mean this time. Can you please make it clear? Did you mean the parameters or what?

Comment: For my gui, when i click on the button 'Add' it will minus off from the medicalproduct table. How would i call this method **public void updateQuantity(String quantity,String id)** when i click on my button 'Add'. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Ok just do       updateQuantity( quantity, id);     where the quantity is the string value from the jTextField and id is the string id of the field you are updating. I assume you id is string. but you can modify to suit your program.

Comment: `String quantity = textFieldQuantity.getText();
    String id = null;
    
    try {
     updateQuantity(quantity, id);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    
     e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
     
     e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ` I've added this and it does not seem to work

Comment: I guess you are new to these stuffs. But you have set the id to null so it has nothing to query. You must set the id to the particular field's primary key or id's data that you want to modify.

Comment: yes, I'm new to it. I've managed to do it. THANK YOU so much for your help. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Introduction to Java Programming - Y. Daniel Liang. their companion site is [here](http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/intro9e/toc.html)